# Keras LSTM model has very low accuracy

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to build a model that takes a sentence as input, takes each word and tries to predict the next word. My input and output both are a 3D matrix with (number of sentences, number of words per sentence, dimension of word embedding). Input is e. g. "I like green apples" while the output is "like green apples _", each word embedded as a 300 dimensional vector used from pre-trained GoogleWord2Vec. I only use an Input Layer, an LSTM layer and a TimeDistributed Output layer.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           (None, 15, 300)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
rnn (LSTM)                   (None, 15, 300)           721200    
_________________________________________________________________
tanh (TimeDistributed)       (None, 15, 300)           90300     
=================================================================


#building the model
words = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(None, maxSeqLength, numDimensions), name = "input") #inputs
hiddenStates = keras.layers.LSTM(300, input_shape=(batch_size, maxSeqLength, numDimensions), return_sequences = True, name = "rnn")(words)
timeOutput = TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(numDimensions, activation='relu'), name = "tanh")(hiddenStates)
model = keras.models.Model(input = words, output = timeOutput)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr = 0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

#training the model
model.fit(input, output, batch_size=batch_size, epochs = 100, verbose=1)
```

My problem is that when I run the model my accuracy is like 0,05. Trying different learning rates or inputs does not improve it. Can somebody tell me why my model might fail? The goal of the model is that I want to use the last hidden state as a vector representing the input sentence.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132167/4132383 since you're using loss='mse', you might be interpreting the 0.05 wrong. But anyway this might be the wrong approach and you could switch to a categorical loss and softmax activation after the last layer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you're saying I should use softmax activation and categorical loss in my "timeOutput" layer? But then I would have to change my output to one-hot encoded vectors, right? Or